# I want to Solve Below equation in java for button click event

Tags: java

When I click on button the result display as Nan. And if I provide value of `T` directly for Example `T=15` than 15 will be print out.

This is Formula.

```
T = (P*R)/ ((S*E)-(0.6)*P)
```

Where `P` , `R` , `S` is variable from Text Box.
And `E` is variable from Drop Down Box.

Comment: post your code to get help.

Comment: have you converted the values from texbox to int ??

Comment: I guess you are dividing by 0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, `T` is going to be a decimal, so the first thing you should look into is how to cast from a Java `String` to a `double`, using the `Double.parseDouble()` method, which you can read about [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).

If you don't know how to grab the value from the text box itself, then you should read about `JTextField`, and its methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html). Finally, if you don't know how to get a value from a `JComboBox`, then you can read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Once you've worked out how to get the value from the text box or drop down list and parse it into the correct data type, you can get onto performing the calculation.

```
double t = (p * r)/((s * e) - (0.6) * p);
```

You'll also notice I've given you very little code. This is because you've given me nothing to work with. Happy reading!

Answer (score 0):

Check your input for `S` & `E`, if it is 0 (zero) then your output always show `NaN` what stands for 'Not A Number'